# Cannot find "Grammar.txt" in python-sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I'm trying to generate html documentation using Python Sphinx under Windows, I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'c:\\python27\\sphinx.egg\\sphinx\\pycode\\Grammar.txt'
```

However, when I open the sphinx.egg, the file "Grammar.txt" is present...

Here's the log it provided

```
# Sphinx version: 1.1.3
# Python version: 2.7.3
# Docutils version: 0.9.1 release
# Jinja2 version: 2.6 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 188, in main
    warningiserror, tags)   
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\application.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.setup_extension(extension)
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\application.py", line 247, in
setup_extension
    mod = __import__(extension, None, None, ['setup'])
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 26, in <module>  
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\pycode\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\pycode\pgen2\driver.py", line 126, in load_grammar
    g = pgen.generate_grammar(gt)
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\pycode\pgen2\pgen.py", line 383, in generate_grammar
    p = ParserGenerator(filename)
File "c:\python27\sphinx.egg\sphinx\pycode\pgen2\pgen.py", line 15, in  __init__
    stream = open(filename) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\python27\\sphinx.egg\\sphinx\\pycode\\Grammar.txt'
```

Anyone has a clue why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out why it wasn't finding the file "Grammar.txt". At first, I moved the sphinx-quickstart.exe inside my source folder. Instead, it is better (also the proper way to do) to just launch sphinx-quickstart.exe from its default folder and then at the question:

> > Enter the root path for documentation.
>
> > Root path for the documentation [.]: "PathToYourSourceFolder"

You enter your source folder path at this question.

Hope this helps someone !