# Cannot find “Grammar.txt” in lib2to3

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, pip, ironpython, networkx

I am trying to get NetworkX running under IronPython on my machine.  From other sources I think other people have made this work.  (https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/news.html)

I am running IronPython 2.7 2.7.5.0 on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 in VisualStudio 2015 Community Edition.

The problem is that when I

```
import NetworkX as nx
```

I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SourceModules\CodeKatas\IronPythonExperiment\ProveIronPython\ProveIronPython\ProveIronPython.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gml.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\refactor.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\fixer_util.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\pygram.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\pgen2\driver.py", line 121, in load_grammar
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\pgen2\pgen.py", line 385, in generate_grammar
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\pgen2\pgen.py", line 15, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\Grammar.txt'.: C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\lib2to3\Grammar.txt
```

The bottom line seems to be that NetworkX wants Grammar.txt to be in the lib2to3 directory of my IronPython installation.

I have tried several things, but no success.  Some are too dumb to admit to in public, but I did try

- running from command line: (ipy myExecutable.py)
- pip installing another package (BeautifulSoup), but that package installed and
  instantiated with no problems.
- I also looked at
  [Cannot find "Grammar.txt" in python-sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649565/cannot-find-grammar-txt-in-python-sphinx)
  , but it did not seem to have any explanation that helped my specific
  case.

**My Question:**
How can I resolve this problem with 'import NetworkX' raising this exception?

Comment: A lib2to3 import snuck into networkx-1.10 and networkx-1.11 which is the latest release.  Could you try the development release from the github site?  The lib2to3 library import is removed from that.  https://github.com/networkx/networkx/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thank you Aric.  I will try the development release now.  (I actually thought about emailing you this directly, but I didn't want to trouble you, so thanks for helping me here.)

Comment: Aric, your suggestion works and I am now able to proceed with further work.  Thank you very much.  If you put your suggestion as a formal Answer I will accept it.  (This also keeps my question off the Unanswered list.)

Comment: I think putting it in an answer makes it easier for a Google Search to find than if it is just in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lib2to3 import snuck into networkx-1.10 and networkx-1.11 which is the latest release. Try the development release from the github site. (That will soon be networkx-2.0). The lib2to3 library import has been removed since the networkx-1.11 release. github.com/networkx/networkx/archive/master.zip